# How to deploy Xamarin Forms App to iOS device for Testing

Tags: xamarin.forms

I m using VS2017 for Xamarin forms app development. With VS2017,I can use Android simulator and I can deploy the simple xamarin forms hello app to my Physical Android phone(after doing some settings on the android phone).

My problem now is How do I deploy my same Xamarin Forms hello app in VS2017 in my Windows 10 PC to an iOS device? right now, I have a macBook Pro and iphone6. I try the mac agent but this only for iOS simulator.

Please help. any link or help is very much appreciated.

**Update 1:**

The confusing part is App ID. Say, I created an AppID in Apple Portal called MySwiftDemo and on mac i created a dummy app with Bundle Id : com.FunProject.MyFirstSwiftDemo which I used it in AppID required by the Apple Portal
and I created XF-app in VS call MyVSFirstApp and this is the actual app will be deployed to iOS-device.

1) The app name in Mac and VS are not the same. So the provisioning file is referring everything from mac, Is it ok without Xamarin app name?

2) If I have another Xamarin forms app call My2ndApp to deploy to iOS device, do I need to create another AppID on Apple Portal and Bundle ID on mac?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Deploying_to_a_Device

Answer (score 1):

1. Subscribe to Apple's Developer Program

   > Visit the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) to register. Note that in order to register as an Apple developer, it is necessary to have an Apple ID and costs $100/year
2. Create an iOS Signing Certificate

   - Follow the steps [linked here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Generate_a_Development_Certificate_Manually)
3. Provision your iOS Project and your physical iOS device for Developer Mode

   - Connect your physical iOS device to the USB port on the Mac, then follow the steps [linked here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Provisioning_an_iOS_Device_for_Development)

Comment: If you use VS for MAC it should be easier. On Build2017 Migel and James demonstrated that.

Comment: @Brandon, thank for the links. please refer to my update. Hope you can clear some of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Using **XamarinLivePlayer** we can test the app on Android and iOS

Which was introduced in Microsoft Build 2017 Event(https://build.microsoft.com/).

You can read more at https://www.xamarin.com/live

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mobile-center/

Comment: I am using Enterprise VS2017 and I m not using VS2017 Preview. So, I can not use Xamarin Live Player to debug and deploy, is this correct?

Comment: I think I want to use the old method.